# How to merge data frame with multiple columns with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, left-join

i have made a data frame consisting of codes with following code:

```
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'),as.Date('2019-06-30'),by = "1 
day"))
dates <- as.data.frame(dates)
dates$date_general_ledger <- ymd(dates$date_general_ledger)
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
 `date_general_ledger
1          2015-01-01
2          2015-01-02
3          2015-01-03
4          2015-01-04
5          2015-01-05
6          2015-01-06
```

Then i have data frame consisting dates , account_id and value

```
`# A tibble: 6 x 3
  account_id date_general_ledger     amount
       <int> <chr>                    <dbl>
1     A      2015-01-01                 110
2     A      2015-01-03                 200
3     B      2015-01-02                  50
```

I am trying below code to merge

```
  `dates %>%
  left_join(df3, by="account_id")
```

It is not bring 2015-01-02 value as "NA" against "A" because it is not considering account_id in the joining.

Comment: Make the second data.frame also reproducible.

Comment: Do you want to join by `date_general_ledger` instead? What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah my expected output is all account id which have dates missing as per the dates dataframe should have date and account id but the amount/value will be zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` :

```
result <- tidyr::complete(df3, account_id, 
                          date_general_ledger = dates$date_general_ledger, 
                          fill = list(amount = 0))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   account_id date_general_ledger amount
#   <chr>      <chr>                <dbl>
# 1 A          2015-01-01             110
# 2 A          2015-01-02               0
# 3 A          2015-01-03             200
# 4 A          2015-01-04               0
# 5 A          2015-01-05               0
# 6 A          2015-01-06               0
# 7 B          2015-01-01               0
# 8 B          2015-01-02              50
# 9 B          2015-01-03               0
#10 B          2015-01-04               0
#11 B          2015-01-05               0
#12 B          2015-01-06               0
```

**data**

```
df3 <- structure(list(account_id = c("A", "A", "B"), 
date_general_ledger = c("2015-01-01","2015-01-03", "2015-01-02"), 
amount = c(110L, 200L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))

dates <- structure(list(date_general_ledger = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", 
"2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The big issue here is that you have an invalid join. When you join two data data.frames, the column being joined by must be in both data.frames. The `dates` data.frame does not contain the `account_ID` column, so the join you have will not work. The only column they have in common is `date_general_ledger`, so you could join by that.

```
dates %>%
  left_join(df3, by="date_general_ledger") %>%
  tibble()
# A tibble: 1,642 x 3
   date_general_ledger account_id amount
   <date>              <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2015-01-01          A             110
 2 2015-01-02          B              50
 3 2015-01-03          A             200
 4 2015-01-04          NA             NA
 5 2015-01-05          NA             NA
 6 2015-01-06          NA             NA
 7 2015-01-07          NA             NA
 8 2015-01-08          NA             NA
 9 2015-01-09          NA             NA
10 2015-01-10          NA             NA
# ... with 1,632 more rows

df3 %>%
  full_join(dates, by="date_general_ledger") %>%
  tibble()
# A tibble: 1,642 x 3
   account_id date_general_ledger amount
   <chr>      <date>               <dbl>
 1 A          2015-01-01             110
 2 A          2015-01-03             200
 3 B          2015-01-02              50
 4 NA         2015-01-04              NA
 5 NA         2015-01-05              NA
 6 NA         2015-01-06              NA
 7 NA         2015-01-07              NA
 8 NA         2015-01-08              NA
 9 NA         2015-01-09              NA
10 NA         2015-01-10              NA
# ... with 1,632 more rows
```

Are either of these what you are looking for? If not, then your `dates` data.frame needs to have another column.

There are also some minor issues with the preparation of your `dates` data.frame.

```
# This code throws an error. You should set by = "day"
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2019-06-30'), by = "1 
day"))

# This code also throws an error because that column was not defined in the data.frame.
dates$date_general_ledger <- ymd(dates$date_general_ledger)
```

The following code works to set up `dates`.

```
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'),as.Date('2019-06-30'),by = "day"))
dates <- data.frame(date_general_ledger = ymd(dates))
```

Here is code to set up the abbreviated `df3`

```
df3 <- tibble(account_id = LETTERS[1:3], 
              date_general_ledger = ymd(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-02")),
              amount = c(110, 200, 50))
```

Comment: thanks much for your response. One thing that my code is doing it is bringing date which are missing in entire data where as what i want is to bring missing dates for each account ids.